# Plurals and third person in LanguageTool (using regex?)

Tags: regex, xml, spell-checking, languagetool

I am terrible with grammar in general, and with `s`'s in particular : I forget to put an `s` at the end of plural nouns and verbs in the third person, and I put random `s`'s at the end of singular nouns and verbs not in the third person.

I use `Texstudio` with `LanguageTool` to edit scientific papers. Unfortunately `LanguageTool` misses most of those `s`'s mistakes I regularly make.

I know the basics of adding rules to LanguageTools, including rules using `regex`.
But I have a hard time coming up with a rule that would best catch those `s`'s mistakes.

***My question*** : Any idea what that(these) rule(s) could look like?

**Notes :**

- I am not attached to using `regex`. Any suggestion using regex when effective and other strategies otherwise is welcome
- What really matters to me is a rule that flags potential mistakes. I don't care much about the rule proposing an appropriate correction. Drawing my attention to potential mistakes suffices  : once I see them, I can recognize them and correct them.
- **What I have so far** is a very coarse rule which simply flags every word finishing with an `s` (`\w*s\b`). As I write and encounter words that naturally finish with an `s` (like "is" or "this"), I progressively add them as exceptions to the rule. That helps a little, but it is both too inclusive -- too many words get flagged, which means I start paying less and less attention to flagged words -- and not inclusive enough -- it doesn't identify any word for which an `s` is potentially missing.
- As suggested by my current `\w*s\b` strategy, I am open to partial solutions. Any suggestion better than `\w*s\b` that I could implement in LanguageTool is much welcome.

Comment: Regex would be good at finding positives for `'s` (the sign of the genitive), but it would be harder to catch incorrect usage.  For example, how could a regex by itself distinguish `bats`, a correct plural of `bat`, from `bats`, an incorrect genitive for `bat's` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : that's what I figured. I added a comment to my question specifying I am happy with any suggestion that uses `regex` when effective, and any other strategy otherwise.

Comment: I think a full solution would require a grammar parser.  Regex might be a part of it, but it would only be one tool used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : agreed. As suggested by my current strategy `\w*s\b` I am open to partial solutions. Anything better than `\w*s\b` that could be implemented in LanguageTool is much welcome.